# 'mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: mongodb

I want to learn Mongo so I installed MongoDB for Windows from the official site. I just got something called Mongo Compass on my pc. I can't run mongod command on cmd, as it says: 'mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command. So I can't move on. How can I fix the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, probably this could help: https://dangphongvanthanh.wordpress.com/2017/06/12/add-mongos-bin-folder-to-the-path-environment-variable/

Comment: Compass doesn't come in the same package as the server software, did you install both packages?